# .NET 6 with React won't connect to SignalR

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-6.0

I want to migrate my .NET Core 5 React project to .NET 6, but I'm facing some issues with SignalR.

I've followed the article step by step from this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to implement SignalR with .NET 6. And still I'm getting the same error as shown here: [SignalR Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auHxj.png)

Any assistance will be appreciated. My code snippets:

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44413/")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");

app.Run();
```

ChatHub.cs

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

Layout.js

```
const connection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("/chathub")
  .configureLogging(SignalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build();

async function start() {
  try {
    console.log("SignalR Connecting....");
    await connection.start();
    console.log("SignalR Connected.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    setTimeout(start, 5000);
  }
}

connection.onclose(async () => {
  await start();
});

// Start the connection.
start();
```

SetupProxy.js

```
const createProxyMiddleware = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const { env } = require("process");

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
  ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}`
  : env.ASPNETCORE_URLS
  ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(";")[0]
  : "http://localhost:9738";

const context = ["/weatherforecast", "/chathub"];

module.exports = function (app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: "Keep-Alive",
    },
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this in the future. Once I removed the headers from the proxy middleware and added `ws: true` (enable websockets). It started as expected.

From

```
const createProxyMiddleware = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const { env } = require("process");

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
  ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}`
  : env.ASPNETCORE_URLS
  ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(";")[0]
  : "http://localhost:9738";

const context = ["/weatherforecast", "/chathub"];

module.exports = function (app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: "Keep-Alive",
    },
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

To

```
const createProxyMiddleware = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const { env } = require("process");

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
  ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}`
  : env.ASPNETCORE_URLS
  ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(";")[0]
  : "http://localhost:9738";

const context = ["/weatherforecast", "/chathub"];

module.exports = function (app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    ws: true, // <-- Add this
    headers: { // <-- Remove this
      Connection: "Keep-Alive", // <-- Remove this
    }, // <-- Remove this
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

Comment: thanks for this, I wasted about 30 minutes trying to diagnose as well. They really should include these items commented out as part of the template with websockets being pretty common.

Comment: In addition to this, your hub cannot be named /ws.

Comment: In my case, `const createProxyMiddleware = require..` did not work. Curly brackets were necesssary such as `const { createProxyMiddleware } = require..`. Furthermore, I had to add `changeOrigin: true` to the middleware options.