# SignalR connection works with console app but not with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have the following relevant code on my ASP.NET server:

```
// TrackingHub.cs
public class TrackingHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendLocationData(LocationData locationData)
    {
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveLocationData", locationData);
        Console.WriteLine($"{locationData.Latitude}, {locationData.Longitude}");
    }
}

// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddSignalR()
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
    });
});

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.MapHub<TrackingHub>("/tracking");
```

Now on my .NET console app, I have the following relevant code. It works well and I receive the location data from it on my asp.net server:

```
HubConnection? hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
     .WithUrl("http://localhost:5191/tracking")
     .Build();

// stuff...
if (hubConnection != null)
{
    await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendLocationData", locationData);
}
```

And finally, this is the code I have on my react (NextJS) app:

```
const page = () => {
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://localhost:5191/tracking')
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build()

    connection.on('ReceiveLocationData', (locationData) => {
        console.log(locationData)
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const startConnection = async () => {
            try {
                await connection.start()
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log("Failed to start connection: ", error)
            }
        }

        startConnection()
    }, []);

    return (
        <Map />
    )
}
```

The connection, however, is not working with the React app. Note that other connections from the react app to the server work just fine (like regular GET or POST methods). I also checked the transport type being used by the working console app to see if websocket protocol is even functional or supported, and it was indeed using Websockets, which I checked using [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473648/determine-transport-method-in-signalr-core].

Here is an image of what I am getting on the console:

[image: Errors from SignalR connection in react app]

Comment: I don't know if you ommited this part, but you are missing  services.AddSignalR()

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade yeah my bad I will add it I just didn't include it in my post. The console app works, so any important missing details aren't really the issue here. But somehow opening the connection from the react app doesn't work. The code I'm using for react doesn't have any issue I think. I even checked a video and replicated what they did too and still got the same error.

Comment: If you are using react app, you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112430/7687666, below answer is used for nextjs app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JasonPan answer partially worked to mitigate the issue (which was adding `skipNegotiation: true, transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets` to the client side connection).

However, it didn't address the real issue as the connection should work regardless even without those options. I asked on the aspnetcore github repo and they suggested that it might be because I am using an endpoint called "tracking" with adblock, and that was it https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49918.
So, changing the endpoint name or disabling adblock makes it work without having to add `skipNegotiation: true, transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets`.

Comment: Like mentioned on github. It's possible the fact that you're using "tracking" in the url that's causing ad block to trigger.

Comment: Yeah, that was the reason actually. I changed the endpoint name, and it works with the adblock now. I forgot to update my comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Add the proxy setting like below in your `next.config.js` file.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = [
    {
      context: [
        "/tracking"
     ],
      target: "http://localhost:5191", 
      changeOrigin: true,  
      logLevel: "debug",
      rejectUnauthorzied: true, 
      secure: false,            
      strictSSL: true,          
      withCredentials: true,
      // It is important
      ws: true
    }
  ]

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Then in my side, I also change the code like below.

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("http://localhost:55377/mainhub", {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  // we can enable client logging to check more details
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug).build()
```

**Test Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I just added skipNegotiation and transport properties to the connection like you suggested and it worked. I don't think this config is valid for NextJS because it can't be an array but even as an object, the fields are incorrect. Regardless, I didn't need it anyways. But then that begs the question, what if some client doesn't support websockets and has to rely on SSE or long polling?

Comment: @MuaathAsali Thanks for your trying, we have the `HttpTransportType.LongPolling`, no worries.